# Java Azure SB Connection with SAS token

Tags: java, azure, azureservicebus, azure-sdk

```
ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithSASAuthentication(config.getSbNamespace(), "RootManageSharedAccessKey", SAS_KEY, ".servicebus.windows.net");
ServiceBusContract service = ServiceBusService.create();
service.getTopic(topicID);
```

This code snippet is used to connect to Service Bus using SAS Key. I'm looking for possibility of connection with SAS token which looks like this:

```
SharedAccessSignature sr=https%3a%2f%2fmynamespace.servicebus.windows.net%2fMyTestQueue&sig=fFWmdMmWjsdTqPyhyvRS9LQqLjJNPc87xhInhYai9OM%3d&se=1453286209&skn=MyQueue_Listen
```

I receive 401 Unauthorized using this code. I don't have possibility to go back to SAS key. Does Azure SDK for Java support this? Is there different way to connect?

Answer (score 1):

The `".servicebus.windows.net"` looks a bit off (the `.` in the beginning).

FYI: There's an ASB [Java client repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java) repository with issue tracker. You could check there as well.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use Azure Service Bus SDK for Java to do something like to get a topic via topic id, but you didn't know how to pass the shared access key to the method `configureWithSASAuthentication`.

I suggested that you need to follow the offical tutorial [How to use Service Bus topics and subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions) carefully to know how to get the shared access key for a service bus instance and to use it via SDK.

[image]

The `SharedAccessSignature sr=https%3a%2f%2fmynamespace.servicebus.windows.net%2fMyTestQueue&sig=fFWmdMmWjsdTqPyhyvRS9LQqLjJNPc87xhInhYai9OM%3d&se=1453286209&skn=MyQueue_Listen` that you were looking for is for calling the related REST APIs, not directly used in the code with SDK.

Hope it helps.